# problem with Tomcat 9 and Spring org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have installed tomcat 9 again, also the java jdk but I still cannot solve the problem, I'm desperate, I don't know why, I must have something wrong in the classpath

```
mar 29, 2021 11:09:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Server initialization in [462] milliseconds
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start 
component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/solution-code-spring-mvc- 
adding-data-to-the-spring-model]]

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/solution-code-spring-mvc-adding- 
data-to-the-spring-model]]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
... 40 more
```

[image]
[image]

here is the project

https://github.com/darbyluv2code/spring-and-hibernate-for-beginners/tree/master/02-spring-mvc-5/solution-code-spring-mvc-adding-data-to-the-spring-model

i've downloaded these jar files

https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/5.0.3.RELEASE/

Comment: Please add some details to your question: how do you run Tomcat, what format is your application (is it a WAR archive)? The main error is `ClassNotFoundException` since you lack `spring-web.jar` in your application.

Comment: it's is not war file, i'm adding some pictures

Comment: So, you are starting Tomcat through Eclipse (important missing information). Eclipse sometimes _"forgets"_ to copy some libraries into the deployment directory. Removing the project from the server, cleaning the server and adding the application again, usually helps.

Comment: Choose "Clean..." from the server contextual menu it may help you

Comment: i cleaned Tomcat server and error is still happening, i've created another project and happens the same, maybe the problem is my jdk or classpath?

Comment: follow this one it will help you https://www.pegaxchange.com/2018/01/24/java-web-project-with-spring-framework/